# Visual Studio Code hitting invisible breakpoints in compiled .Next files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

I'm fairly new to NextJS but I'm seeing something that's distrupting my workflow.

I've set up my launch.json as per https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging#using-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-code

When I run my application from the selected launch config I am able to hit the breakpoints I expect within my TypeScript files no problem, but every time I start my application I notice VSC is hitting breakpoints that don't exist within files in the /.Next folder. As you can see from the screenshot, it thinks this is a breakpoint in my authProvider.tsx file.

Can anyone explain why this might be, and how I stop it from happening?

[image]

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false, /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */// "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
    /* Include every ts file in source folder */
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
    /* exclude everything in  node_modules */
  ]
}
```

And my launch config is an exact copy of what is shown on the link above.

Comment: Do you have source maps enabled for NextJS?
See: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/source-maps

Comment: Note that these are disabled by default for prod builds.

Comment: I do indeed. See tsconfig provided above.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by simply deleting that compiled file inside of the .next folder. The next time I ran it, it hit the correct breakpoint in the source file.